# how to escape double quotes in jsrender

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsrender

How to escape double quotes in jsrender. In my sample return the value includes double quotes. i add some custom Attribute through jrender template. how to achieve this . For example

```
myfield = "Sno";
value ={{:myfield}}
```

myfield as return "Sno" so i cant get jsrender . please help me how to achieve this

Comment: I can't understand your qustion. What do you mean? > `I can't get jsrender`

Comment: Voted to close, please provide a clear explanation and reproduction case. If you have variables with double quotes in them (encoded as \" in JSON), `jsrender` has no problem displaying those whatsoever.

Comment: Also vote to close. Alternatively can you create a jsfiddle showing your example, (including your proposed solution below)? Otherwise, can you remove this question, as it is confusing for all. There is no special need to escape double quotes in JsRender. They get rendered correctly without additional escaping. –

Answer (score 0):

use this below syntax to resolve the issue

```
{{:" +myfield+"}}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this

`{{>myField}}` instead of `{{:myField}}`